# ImageViews which is in ListView doesn't displayed

Tags: android, listview, caching, android-asynctask, android-imageview

I have ListView with EventAdapter.

```
public class EventAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
...
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
     ...
     cache.imgIcon.setImageDrawable(ImgCache.setImg(url, progressBar));
     ...
}
```

ImgCache its class for caching images.

```
public class ImgCache {
    public static HashMap<String, Drawable> imgCache;

    // get img from cache if exist, or download and put in cache
    public static Drawable setImg(final String link, final ProgressBar progressBar) {
        final Drawable[] image = {null};
        if (imgCache.containsKey(link)) {
            image[0] = imgCache.get(link);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Drawable>() {
                @Override
                protected Drawable doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    URL url = null;
                    try {
                        url = new URL(link);
                        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                        image[0] = Drawable.createFromStream(connection.getInputStream(), "src");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    imgCache.put(link, image[0]);
                    return image[0];
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }.execute();
        }
        return image[0];
    }
}
```

What the problem is?

After I open my `Activity` with `ListView` all images begin loading. But after the loading is finished they don't displayed. It is looks like:

[image]

Then I try to scroll 2 items down and then return to previous position. After this manipulation I can see 2 upper items with images. Also all  images down are also visible when I scroll to them.

[image]

Comment: just a warning: `HashMap<String, Drawable>` depending on how many drawables you have and the device the user is using you will have OutOfMemory error on your app.

Comment: Can I get size of this HashMap anyway? And what size must cache be?

Comment: for caching of images (I usually use Bitmap, but Drawable are just as fine) I would suggest you to use LruCache (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/LruCache.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your problem, it seems like you need to refresh your `ListView` after the images has been downloaded (because when you scroll they do appear):

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I also think about it, but where I must call this line?

Answer (score 2):

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is asynchronous so the flow for your app is:

ListView Item needs to be displayed -> Calls Adapter.getView(...) for List item -> if image is not in cache, execute AsyncTask and return (not waiting for result)
So, when you scroll down and back up, the Adapter.get(...) method is called again, however this time the image is in cache so it returns the Drawable object which is displayed

One way to resolve this issue would be to have a callback to the Adapter from the AsyncTask that will update the image once it is retrieved calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on the Adapter, setting specific Drawable directly or something similar (display a loading gif for images in the meanwhile?)

Or

Call the AsyncTask `get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` method which will block the man thread and wait for the AsyncTask to finish. After it is finished then it will return the result (your Drawable in this case). This will cause the main UI thread to hang while fetching images, so not optimal way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your view loads and populates your list OnCreate, but at that time your Async task hasn't returned your list yet so when getView calls your cache it's empty, due to android View Recycling when you scroll it calls getView again, this time your cache has been populated.

I recommend that onPostExecute you call `NotifyDataSetChanged` on your ListView adapter, this will force a redraw once your have your images.